# Can I get a list of services registered to TfsTeamProjectCollection

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am using PowerShell to connect to TFS and perform various operation. I can do this:

```
$Uri = New-Object System.Uri("http://mycompany.com/tfs/collection")
$t = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection($Uri, $TfsClientCredentials)
$t.Authenticate()

$CSS = $t.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.ICommonStructureService])
```

It all works. However I can't find a list of the built in services like ICommonStructureService I've used here. I've located a few pages that list some of them like:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/taylaf/2010/02/23/introducing-the-tfsconnection-tfsconfigurationserver-and-tfsteamprojectcollection-classes/
but this is outdated.

Is there anywhere I can see the complete list?

Comment: Reflector and dotPeek offer a nice way to find all classes that implement the required interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access additional services by using one of the `GetService` methods that the abstract class [TfsConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958(v=vs.120).aspx#Getting%20Additional%20Team%20Foundation%20Services) defines and that [TfsConfigurationServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.tfsconfigurationserver(v=vs.120).aspx) and [TfsTeamProjectCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.tfsteamprojectcollection(v=vs.120).aspx) implement.

When you use the TfsTeamProjectCollection class, you access the services for the team project collection. Below is a complete list:
[image]

More detail info please refer this article: [Getting Additional Team Foundation Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958(v=vs.120).aspx#Getting%20Additional%20Team%20Foundation%20Services)

Comment: I notice Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Client.GitRepositoryService is not present in this list nor on the referenced page. That's the one that started me looking for a complete list.